# Most efficient way to transfrom a 2d array to a different coordinate system using a function, then interpolate the resultant holes

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, scipy

To start, Im basically trying to go from this:

[image]

To this:

[image]

Given that each coordinate [x,y]  correspond with a given point in the second image after a function is applied to x and y. f(x,y)=coords of the second image for the value of [x,y]. The way Im handling this part as of now is to make a "map" array of x and y and the lookup in that array to find the new point. so mapArrayX[x] will give the new x value and mapArray[y] will give the new Y value. The Issue with this is that I have to iterate over the entire image (256,000 points) and that takes roughly .4 seconds. Is there a better way to do this?

The second issue is after transforming the coordinates I get an image with holes in it that looks like this:

[image]

which I make look like the image above without the holes by doing this:

```
dewarpedImage[dewarpedImage == 0] = np.nan
x = np.arange(0, dewarpedImage.shape[1])
y = np.arange(0, dewarpedImage.shape[0])
# mask invalid values
dewarpedImage = np.ma.masked_invalid(dewarpedImage)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x, y)
# get only the valid values
x1 = xx[~dewarpedImage.mask]
y1 = yy[~dewarpedImage.mask]
newarr = dewarpedImage[~dewarpedImage.mask]

startTime = time.time()
dewarpedImage = interpolate.griddata((x1, y1), newarr.ravel(),
                                     (xx, yy),
                                     method='linear')
```

This takes roughly 3 seconds to perform. Is there a faster way to do this maybe. I ideally need to get this whole process to go from taking 3+seconds to less than 1 second.

Here is my conversion function/how I generate my mapping:

```
RANGE_BIN_SIZE = .39


def rangeBinToRange(rangeBin):
    return rangeBin * RANGE_BIN_SIZE


def azToDegree(azBin):
    degree = math.degrees(math.asin((azBin - 127.5) * 0.3771/(0.19812*255)))
    return degree


def makeWarpMap():
    print("making warp maps")
    xMap = np.zeros((1024, 256))
    yMap = np.zeros((1024, 256))
    for az in range(256):
        for rang in range(1024):
            azDegree = azToDegree(az)
            dist = rangeBinToRange(rang)
            x = round(dist * math.sin(math.radians(azDegree)) + 381)
            y = round(dist * math.cos(math.radians(azDegree)))
            xMap[rang][az] = x
            yMap[rang][az] = y

    np.save("warpmapX", xMap)
    np.save("warpmapY", yMap)


print(azToDegree(0))
if not path.exists("warpmapX.npy") or not path.exists("warpmapY.npy"):
    makeWarpMap()

data = np.load(filename)
xMap = np.load("warpmapX.npy")
yMap = np.load("warpmapY.npy")

dewarpedImage = np.zeros((400, 762))
print(data.shape)
for az in range(256):
    azslice = data[:, az]
    for rang in range(1024):
        intensity = azslice[rang]
        x = xMap[rang][az]
        y = yMap[rang][az]
        dewarpedImage[int(y)][int(x)] = intensity
```

Comment: May be use cv.LogPolar function from OpenCV?

Comment: Can you provide us image data and your conversion function so we can help improve conversion speed?

Answer (score 1):

You have holes in your converted image because your conversion does not span the entire polar image. I would recommend to do the reverse conversion. In other words, for each `(X,Y)` in polar image, find corresponding point `(x,y)` in cartesian image and get that color. That way you won't need to deal with holes at all and it will give you a full image (it will get rid of 3sec conversion). If you provide your conversion function, I can help you do the reverse conversion.

Comment: @cheesemas46 could you also please provide a small sample of image? maybe a 10x10 input for debugging. You can also convert most of your loops to array operations which is significantly faster.

Comment: The input image is always gonna be 256x1024 (not sure if that is relevant) and the data are all numbers between say 5 and 100